# How to change a connection arrow in Visio using VBA commands

Tags: vba, visio

Good Afternoon,
I have been trying to write a macro (VBA) to change the properties of a connection arrow in Visio.  For some reason the changes don't seem to happen. I recorded a macro and then modified it for my needs.

Here is the code that I have been using:

```
Sub Macro1(shapeID As Long)

    'Enable diagram services
    Dim DiagramServices As Integer
    DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140 + visServiceVersion150

    Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
    UndoScopeID1 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Manual Edit")
    Application.ActiveWindow.page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shapeID).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormWidth).FormulaForceU = "GUARD(EndX-BeginX)"
    Application.ActiveWindow.page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shapeID).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormHeight).FormulaForceU = "GUARD(EndY-BeginY)"
    Application.ActiveWindow.page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shapeID).CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent, 2, 0).FormulaForceU = "0.6024533433537" & " in"
    Application.ActiveWindow.page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shapeID).CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent, 3, 0).FormulaForceU = "0.6024533433537" & " in"
    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, True
    'Restore diagram services
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices

End Sub
```

Comment: You need change line ends?

Comment: Hi, It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Are you wanting to change the arrow (line end) as per Surrogate's comment or are you trying to change the geometry / vertices of a connector?  It looks like the latter based on the code.  If you're targeting a dynamic connector though, this is a special case where Visio manages the geometry itself depending on the style (straight / right-angle / curved) and so you might want a different approach than writing directly to the geometry cells.  Could you ellaborate on what you're wanting to do and what connector shape you're targeting?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues:

1. first is syntax of sub declaration.  The entry within the parentheses is wrong.  If this is a stand-alone macro, there should be nothing entered within them.
2. For stand-alone, the shape identity is determined by selecting it before macro execution.  Then, add these code lines:

   ```
    Dim vShp as Visio.Shape
    Set vShp = ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
   ```

3). Change your executable lines to be like vShp.CellsSRC....

4). The 2 lines guarding width and height may be redundant and unnecessary.

5). The next 2 lines try to control connector routing.  Forget it.  Easier to herd cats.  However, there may be suitable options.  See replies 8 and 9 in this link:  http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=1916.msg8680#msg8680